# Where is the select option current value stored?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-select

A `<select>` element looks like this:

```
<select id="ok">
    <option value="one">First</option>
    <option value="two" selected>Second</option>
</select>
```

Initially, the `Second` text value is shown, because the `selected` attribute is present.

If I manually change it (using mouse click), it shows the new chosen value in UI, but the `<select>` remains the same in HTML:

```
<select id="ok">
    <option value="one">First</option>
    <option value="two" selected>Second</option>
</select>
```

I can get the current select value:

```
document.getElementById('ok').value
```

or the current selected index:

```
document.getElementById('ok').selectedIndex
```

via JavaScript (or jQuery), but I don't know where these values come from.

Are they stored in DOM or somewhere else?
How does JavaScript know which is the current value in UI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it stored in DOM?

Yes, it is stored in the DOM.

Whenever a change event is detected DOM is updated and the updated value is stored in the `value` object.

When you use `document.getElementById("ok").value` you are able to access the latest selection in JavaScript.

You can check this in:

#### Firefox Inspector view

1. Show DOM Properties

   [image: Firefox - Show DOM Properties]
2. Filter by `value`:

   [image: Filter value attribute]

#### Chrome DevTools

1. Select the element > Properties

   [image: Chrome - Properties]
2. Expand the `select` and use the vertical scroll to go to `value`:

   [image: Chrome - value]

Comment: Under `Properties` I have `select`, `HTMLSelectElement`, `HTMLElement`, `Element`, `Node`, `EventTarget`, `Object`.
Is the `value` from the right side under `select`? That one is updated (all I need to do is to change the focus in DOM and to select again the `<select>` element).